# Exporting Stock Prices of Multiple Companies to Different Columns to Excel using R

Tags: r, excel

I would like to export historical stock prices of multiple companies to an Excel document using R. I am running into the problem of how to export all the prices in different columns.

For example, I can export Apple's adjusted prices to an excel sheet, but don't know how to add another company on to the next column (and so on). Code as follows:

```
library(quantmod)
library(xlsx)
getSymbols("AAPL", from="2014-01-01", to ="2017-01-01")
write.xlsx(AAPL[,6], file.choose(), row.names=TRUE)
```

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: `write.xlsx` is designed to work on a data.frame, so it's probably easiest to convert to one. You may want to turn the rownames into a column so you don't lose the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want.

```
# assumes codes are known beforehand
codes <- c("MSFT","SBUX","S","AAPL","ADT")
urls <- paste0("https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=",codes,"&output=csv")
paths <- paste0(codes,"csv")
missing <- !(paths %in% dir(".", full.name = TRUE))
missing

# simple error handling in case file doesn't exists
downloadFile <- function(url, path, ...) {
# remove file if exists already
if(file.exists(path)) file.remove(path)
# download file
tryCatch(
download.file(url, path, ...), error = function(c) {
# remove file if error
if(file.exists(path)) file.remove(path)
# create error message
c$message <- paste(substr(path, 1, 4),"failed")
message(c$message)
}
)
}
# wrapper of mapply
Map(downloadFile, urls[missing], paths[missing])
```

Check this out when you have some free time.

https://gist.github.com/jaehyeon-kim/356cf62b61248193db25#file-downloadstockdata

Answer (score 0):

Also, I think you should take a look at these sites.

https://rbresearch.wordpress.com/

https://grollchristian.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/sp500-stock-price-data/

https://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/systematic-investor-toolbox/

https://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/multi-asset-backtest-rotational-trading-strategies/

Enjoy!!